# PHP to HTML 5 using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, local-storage, manifest

I have a difficult problem, we are currently using PHP on our server and I am a PHP programmer.  I have built a site connected to our PHP site that is completely client side HTML 5 and Javascript. I can pass variables from HTML 5 to PHP but I want to import some of the data from the PHP to the HTML pages such as session ...etc. how can I pass PHP sessions to Javascript on another page or access the session data to be used on HTML 5 and Javascript?

The main reason for this is for users with low bandwidth and for the ability of HTML 5 to use local storage and offline capabilities if their line is disconnected so they can post the data at a later time to the PHP pages.

Help would be great?

Comment: To get data from your PHP code simply use AJAX calls. To store a session use cookies.

Comment: `json_encode` is very helpful for formatting php variables for ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not comepletely wrong here, but what you are essentially trying to do is writing data from php to javascript. You could use AJAX as akluth suggested, but I think it is easier to just do the following in the javascript;

```
data = <?php echo $foo; ?>;
```

You should however be careful when saving the session in localstorage since it can be modified by the client. Probably double check once the user attempts to post the data later. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325097/how-can-i-use-html5-local-storage-along-side-php-use-that-for-php-sessions-and?rq=1) for more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get session data in PHP you can use following segment

```
<script>var $_SESSION = <?= json_encode($_SERVER) ?></script>
```

If some data to be maintained on different pages and not require sever data, better you use Session Storage of HTML5 [http://www.xul.fr/en/html5/sessionstorage.php]

This will reduce server load + data transfer and increase speed of your application

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 local storage is not fully supported so some thing that can work anywhere can be do in following way:
First have your PHP Session into JS var:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         var sessionData= <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION); ?>
 </script>
```

Then you will have session data in `sessionData` variable in JSON format. then if you want to use it on different places then simply set and fetch it into cookies via Javascript.

Please tell if some thing is still unclear.